# How to fetch one row from db in asp mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

ASP.net mvc in new for me, for some time I used php (no mvc), but now i'm interested, how I can fetch one row from db? without foreach, for example in title...

here is some code:
controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var pages = (from page in db.Pages where page.PageName == "index" select page).ToList();
            return View(pages);
        }
```

view:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    <% foreach (var item in Model)
       { %>
    <%= Html.Encode(item.Text) %>
    <% }
    %>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fetch one row from db? without foreach" ? ForEach is iterating over the result set, that is passed to the view. Do you want to restrict the resultset to just one record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, instead of `.ToList()` you can use the `.FirstOrDefault()` method, this will return only the first row from the database.

Then in your view you won't need the foreach.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    <%= Html.Encode(item.Model.Text) %>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: If its about fetching "N" number of records, then "Take" is more suitable extension method. Anyways in the above scenario, even the "FirstOrDefault" will work fine.

Comment: <%= Html.Encode(Model.FirstOrDefault().Text)%>   this work's, thank's

Comment: `item.Model.Text` does not work because you probably didn't change the view Model from `IEnumerable<Page>` to just `Page`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing there is creating a List datatype variable and passing it in as the Model to your view. Assuming this is the only piece of data your page needs. Here's what you would do;

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string page = db.pages.where(p => p.PageName == "index").FirstOrDefault().PageName;

            return View(page);
        }
```

There in your page, Model will now be that single string value and you can do this;

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">   
     <%= Model %>
</asp:Content>
```

Although it is best practice to create a ViewModel for the page with the just the properties your page will need and pass that in as the Model.

```
public class MypageViewModel
{
    public string PageName { get; set; }   
}
```

Then do this in the controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            MypageViewModel MyModel = new MypageViewModel();
            MyModel.PageName = db.pages.where(p => p.PageName == "index").FirstOrDefault().PageName;

            return View(MypageViewModel);
        }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Entity Framework:

```
var singleItem = db.pages.Find(id);
```

This will use the Primary Key of your entity.

If you have a composite primary key consisting of multiple properties, Find will still work (because it can take multiple values):

```
var singleItem = db.pages.Find(key1, key2);
```